Why are arrays still in C# when we are actually always using List<T>?
I'm trying to figure out the reason behind the fact that, despite for any practical tasks we are always going to use List<T> in C#, vectors are still there in the langauge. I mean methods like ToArray() and ToList() are there to go back and forth between the two, but at the end of the day we are using the Lists for any practical tasks.
In other words, why we continue to teach and talk about vectors in C# when at the end of the day we find ourselves always using List<T>?

The premise is just incorrect. If you use Lists for everything when an array would suffice, you're doing it wrong.

Arrays are the more basic types. Lots of the .NET API uses arrays. And BTW, also List<T> is based on arrays (see source)

Maybe it was me not being enough clear @GuyIncognito. The point is: why both the structures are present if practically arrays have limitations (for example, not being resizable) and with List you can do everything you can do with array also?

@Jazzpaths There are also cases where you don't want to be able to resize your collection. If for your logic it is important that there are exactly10 integers, use an array instead of a list.

Because Lists are slower and take up more memory.

Show me a multi-dimensional list.

@Fildor although that metaphor would require that every human contained a monkey, occasionally swapping the monkey for a bigger one as needed, which sounds... gruesome

BTW "ToArray() and ToList" - do more than just "to go back and forth between the twos". They also materialize enumerations.

@Fildor Humans didn't "evolve from monkeys" btw. Humans and monkeys share a common ancestor (which went extinct about ~25 million years ago).

@Fildor Just pointing out a misnomer that people often recite. If you want to be rude about it, that's on you.

@Fildor Perhaps because it wasn't clear that was the point, like, at all? :-) Because people often get both things wrong (at least in America). They often think either A) humans evolved from apes or B) humans evolved from monkeys, neither of which are really true. The point you seemed to be making after the quote indicated to me that you thought "while the quote may be true, the lesson is that you sometimes don't need a complex tool to accomplish a simple task" and my point was simply that, regardless of the lesson, the quote itself was not true.

Whatever. It was supposed to be a mildly humorous analogy and you ruined it :(

It's not silly question, actually for lot of developers List is default thing when it comes to collections.
Arrays and List serve different purposes, List is more flexible and its built on top of Array but adds helpful features like resizing and extra methods while arrays are simple way to store fixed-size data and are very fast and memory-efficient.
The reason why we teach arrays is that it helps you to understand how data is stored and managed in memory, It's foundation to understand how more advanced data structures like List works.
The reason why both exist is that sometimes you need the speed and simplicity of array and other times you need flexibility of List.

Lists (and lots of other things) use arrays. This is like asking "why have bricks when we have houses?". If they aren't the right fit for your scenario: fine, don't use them! In the same way that we can use bricks to build a lot of things, not just houses: arrays (as the key metaphor for a contiguous size-fixed-at-creation chunk of managed-heap memory) are used just about everywhere in the runtime and libraries.
If your needs align more with higher-level abstractions like lists, queues, etc: great! Do that!
It should also be noted that a list by necessity involves an array (at least one, possibly many if it is grown gradually) and a wrapper list object, adding additional allocations and overheads that you might need to avoid in low-level library code, although to be fair most of that can be avoided by creating the list with the correct size initially, and bypassing the accessors via MemoryMarshal... but at that point, you are pretty much using it as a gift-wrapped array anyway, so...

N.B. I think ""why have bricks when we have houses?"" is a rather poor analogy; houses are so much more than just one type of (often superficial only) construction material. I think a far more apt analogy is "why have concrete when we have cinderblocks/CMUs"?

@TylerH I didn't want to invest too long thinking of he best simile - "good enough" :) but thanks
